# AppEngine datastore persistency manager get all except

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to get all objects from the datastore except ones already contained in a list.

Eg. PersistencyManager.getObjectsById(List) will return a list of objects with given ID's. I want a getObjectsExcept(List) method that will return all of the objects that are not contained in the given collection.

Comment: by the way, did you get getObjectsById to work? What kind of List does it take? List<Key> ?

Comment: will it be a random list, or would you have some way to predict it beforehand?  also, how many items would there be in total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such function, I am afraid.

You have to manually iterate over all object ids (using a paged query) and ignore those that are in your list.